# Laravel - How can add GET parameter anytime?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I have a Laravel project (`test.com`).

This is redirected from several sites.(`test1.com, test2.com...`)

When redirecting, $_GET has a parameter indicating where it came from.

For example: `test.com?from=test1`, `test.com?from=test2`

I'd like to set "from" parameter to all url on`test.com`.

In other words, when create url, want to add a "from" parameter.

```
test.com/product/1?from=test1
test.com/product/create?from=test1
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using [the `Referer` header value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)?

Comment: The project has already been built. All URL created by route() function on my project.Can I add this 'from' parameter after running route() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous url by [previous method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/urls#accessing-the-current-url):

```php
url()->previous();
```

So you can add the `from` parameter by [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware),

create a middleware file like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class GetReferer
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $from
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $previous = url()->previous().
        $from = parse_url($previous)['host'];
        if ($from == $request->getHost()) {
            $from = $request->session()->get('from');
        } else {
            $request->session()->put('from', $from);
        }
        $request->from = $from;
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

If you want a middleware to run during **every HTTP request** to your application, list the middleware class in the `$middleware property` of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

Comment: Thanks, But first time request remember "from" parameter and next url forget "from" parameter.

Comment: @DaranyKhiev you can try `session()` to store the `from`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't use session on this part.